# python import from higher-level directory while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python2 application is started with run.py which resides in my top-level project directory.  It starts a sub-process for each of many lab instruments.  Each sub-process communicates with its instrument over a serial interface and sends and receives messages with the controller process using zmq pipes.  When the run.py process spawns the sub-processes and the controller process, it passes the connection strings to each.  All processes share a module called zmq_endpoint which contains a class that manages message passing for the system.  zmq_endpoint.py is also in the top-level project directory.  The controller and instrument drivers are in sub-directories or sub-sub-directories of the project directory.

```
project/
    run.py
    zmq_endpoint.py
    ...
    controller/
        controller.py
        ...
    drivers/
        instrument_type1/
            instrument_driver_a.py
            instrument_driver_b.py
        instrument_type2/
            instrument_driver_c.py
```

I'm developing in pyCharm and have succumbed to the siren song of assigning Sources Root and Resource Root markers to navigate the tricky python import process.  When I deploy to my linux target, everything breaks.  The spawned processes can't use ..module import notation since they are spawned independently by the run module with

```
Popen(['python', 'module.py', 'connection1', 'connection2'])
```

None of the sub-processes can find zmq_endpoint.py.

I've been searching for days on importing best-practices and have not found the working answer. So far, I've tried these options:

1. adding a .pth file with the project directory containing zmq_endpoint.py to a directory specified in

   ```
   import site; site.getsitepackages()
   ```
2. adding the project directory to the PATH with

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/home/project
   ```
3. adding the project directory to the PYTHONPATH with

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=/home/project
   ```
4. various tweeks to sys.path which fail due to non-systemic distribution across sub-processes

None of these works. Not sure what the correct answer is.  The zmq_endpoint.py code is part of my project and I'd really like to avoid installing it as a package in site-packages.

Also, is there any application analyzer (like lint for import functionality) that can help diagnose this problem space?  I've got some useful python experience but it seems it falls too short when my application grew larger.

Many thanks for your insights.

Comment: You can only use `from ..module` imports from within a package. Your directories don't seem to contain packages, only a bunch of scripts (no `__init__.py`), so you can't import from different directories without sys.path hacks or similar. And if they were packages you shouldn't execute files inside them as script directly but use `python -m package.module ...` or better have a central entry point.

Comment: No, `popen` isn't really multiprocessing in python. To use the power of multi core CPUS, use `multiprocessing` module which has an almost identical API to that of `threading`.

Comment: But how do I get these sub-processes access to the zmq_endpoint.py code several directory levels up?  Certainly there's a proper method for doing so.